# How can I login in a Minecraft Server in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, sockets, packet, minecraft, handshake

How can I realise VB.Net to send a Packet with enough information to log on into a Minecraft Server? I have these lines of codes, but I don't have a minimal idea how to get the received information that i have requested from the server :/

```
Dim MySocket As New TcpClient(IP, Port)
    Dim Socket As New Wrapped.Wrapped(MySocket.GetStream)

    'Handshake Packet
    Socket.writeInt("4")
    Socket.writeString("localhost")
    Socket.writeShort("25565")
    Socket.writeInt("2")
```

My final idea is to login into a server and keeping on it.
I have read some things on this site, but i'm still confused: http://wiki.vg/Protocol#Handshake

Thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the packet header. Also, you probably want to build the packet in a byte array first, for example using `MemoryStream` with a `BinaryWriter`.

The correct packet looks like this:

```
varint length
varint packetid (0 for handshake)
varint version (4)
length prefixed string serveraddress
UInt16 port
varint nextstate
```

Varints work like this - https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#varints
So their length depends on the value they have.